# Did a migration to database (hrm-master) and got this errors

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'hrm-master.sessions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sessions`
>   where `id` = FCtzXvm1CTIvGJCfWuTVyO1bpyDIDVnt9FlmoCAY limit 1)
>
> in Connection.php line 647 at Connection->runQueryCallback('select *
>   from `sessions` where `id` = ? limit 1',
>   array('FCtzXvm1CTIvGJCfWuTVyO1bpyDIDVnt9FlmoCAY'), object(Closure)) in
>   Connection.php line 607

Comment: If you view the database in something like PHPMyAdmin is the sessions table present?

Answer (score 1):

You have the session configured to use your database at `config/session.php`.

You can read the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#database-sessions

Mae sure you have this table/migration:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

If not, run the following commands:

```
php artisan session:table

php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. Appreciate the great assistance.